# Create a pattern having the letters UTB, followed by a hypen and 3 digits. eg. UTB-001

Tags: html, pattern-matching

am trying to create a pattern which should start and have the 3 letters, UTB and followed by a hyphen, then 3 digits with a format of 001, 002, 003 etc. For example, UTB-001, UTB-012.

This is what I have so far.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<label for ="inspection">Inspection Number</label>
<input type="text" id="inspection" name="inspection_num" pattern="[UTB]{3}'-'[001]{3}">
<button type="submit" name="searchNum">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts, i think i might have have just answered my own question but of course getting the UTB part is still bugging me...here's the code and fiddle;

```
<input type="text" name=" " class="form-control" pattern="[A-Z]{3}[-]\d{3}">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gwLjarpc/